# Encoded string to Normal string in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, in-app-purchase

When i take the product list from itunes connect in my in app purchase app am using following method.

```
   - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    NSLog(@"naveen =0%@",skProducts[0]);
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}
```

In this methode am trying to print the first product  using `NSLog(@"naveen =0%@",skProducts[0]);`

My out for this NSLog is following

naveen =0 SKProduct: 0x7343d50

Please help

Comment: try `NSLog(@"naveen =0%@",[skProducts objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: ok let me try .i will let u knw the result

Comment: @bit-whacker Why do you think that would help? It's the same...

Comment: @bit-whacker  its displaying naveen =0<SKProduct: 0x8b4ca30>

Comment: @Navi Also, what do you expect your code to print? It seems you get a valid object back...

Comment: iam expecting my first product name from itunes connect

Comment: @rmaddy let me read ok

Comment: @Navi And why are you making the assumption that its description is its name? Read the documentation, try logging its `localizedTitle` property instead.

Comment: @H2CO3 i missed the Question sorry.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah i read that document now http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @H2CO3 i didnt understand still how i get the description of a product

Comment: @Navi Which word in "try logging its `localizedTitle` property" didn't you understand?

Comment: thnaks alot @bit-whacker

Comment: @Navi next time ***pretty please*** read the documentation and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navi Try this .Check code between comment lines

```
   - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
   ////////////////////////////////////////  EDIT //////////////////////////////
    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *)skProducts[0];

     NSLog(@"naveen =0%@",product.localizedTitle);
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}
```